# Traveling with an upright bass

Tags: double-bass

This is mostly hypothetical but I was wondering what the safest way to travel with a 3/4 size upright acoustic bass from Minnesota to New York? And what considerations are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hard case is essential. If it is impractical to buy a seat for the instrument, the best way to ensure its survival is to take it to a Fedex company-owned facility, not a franchise, and have them pack the interior of the case. I have had to ship an irreplaceable instrument, and chose them to do the packing. It is worth the expense. De-tune the instrument by turning the pegs back a half-turn.  Also, make sure the airline knows that the instrument must be stored in a pressurized, climate controlled part of the baggage compartment. The low pressure and sub-zero temperatures in regular baggage can wreak havoc on the wood panels, veneers, neck, and frame components of the instrument.

Please post follow up on your experience.

Comment: My son plays double bass. He has not yet flown (up to know it has been better to drive than do all it takes to fly.)  I will pass this information along to him.

Answer (score 1):

If you are flying then you need a hard case.  You obviously can't take it on board with you so it needs protecting when being handled by the luggage crew.

Comment: Would it be any better if I road tripped instead carrying my bass in the car

Comment: You certainly can take it in the car in a soft case.  The way I do it is to flatten back the front passenger seat, and put the bass in endpin end first, to the back, so the head end is to the front of the seat.  You might have a different way of doing it, depending on your car.